# How to build an array of indexes which represent values of different array from the highest to the lowest?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

The title may be a bit confusing so here's an instance. I have two arrays:

```java
int [] scores;
scores = new int[5];  //(5,7,10,3,6)
int [] places;
places = new int[5];  //(1,2,3,4,5)
```

I need to somehow sort the second array (I can't change the first one), so it represents the highness of elements in the first array. 10 is the highest so its place has to be 1st, 3 is the lowest so its place has to be 5th.

After the sorting second array should look like this:

```java
places = {4,2,1,5,3};
```

Here's my code, and I need some help to make it work the way it should.

```java
do {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
            if (scores[i] < scores[j]) {
                temp = places[i];
                places[i] = places[j];
                places[j] = temp;
                flag = true;
            } else {
                flag = false;
            }
        }
    }
} while (flag);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could simply go with any kind of sorting logic on the first array and just do the same operation to the second array.

Comment: @Korashen that don't work "I can't change the first one"

Comment: you question is not clear

Comment: IF your only problem is that you can't change the array you want to sort, you could also copy it and then sort it.

Comment: You can use System.arraycopy() to copy an array. Copy the first array, sort it, apply each sorting step to the second array. After that, you have your original, unchanged first array and the sorted second array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Korashen adviced a pretty good solution,

Another way:
assume all the values of scores are different and positive, you can make a copy of the array,sort it, and by subtaction to know the indexes,

in your example:

before sorting :
`scores = (5,7,10,3,6)`

after sorting :
`scores_sorted = (3,5,6,7,10)`

the value of places will be by the following rule:

`if(scores_sorted[i]-scores[j] == 0)
          places[i] = j`

full example:

```
int[] scores = new int[]{5, 7, 10, 3, 6};
int[] scores_sorted = scores.clone();
int[] places = new int[]{0,1,2,3,4};
sort(scores_sorted);
for(int i=0;i<5;++i){
    for(int j=0;j<5;++j){
        if(scores_sorted[i]-scores[j] == 0){
             places[i] = j;
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Your solution has `O(n²)` instead the optimal `O(n log n)` (eg. when `n=1000` you do `1.000.000` operations when only `3.000` are needed) and don't work as required since modify `scores` array. I can't understand why is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any sorting algorithm over the `places` but, instead comparing the `places`, compare the `scores` indexed by `places`.

Here is the modified `quickSort`:

```
static int partition(int[] iarray, int[] varray, int begin, int end) {
    int pivot = end;

    int counter = begin;
    for (int i = begin; i < end; i++) {
        if (varray[iarray[i]] < varray[iarray[pivot]]) {
            int temp = iarray[counter];
            iarray[counter] = iarray[i];
            iarray[i] = temp;
            counter++;
        }
    }
    int temp = iarray[pivot];
    iarray[pivot] = iarray[counter];
    iarray[counter] = temp;

    return counter;
}

public static void quickSort(int[] iarray, int[] varray, int begin, int end) {
    if (end <= begin) return;
    int pivot = partition(iarray, varray, begin, end);
    quickSort(iarray, varray, begin, pivot - 1);
    quickSort(iarray, varray, pivot + 1, end);
}
```

The only change is add the `varray` argument and the comparison `iarray[i] < iarray[pivot]` to `varray[iarray[i]] < varray[iarray[pivot]]`.

*NOTE:* places must be numbers from `0` to `n - 1`.

If `places` are keys instead indexes, you need an intermediate `Map` to convert the `varray[iarray[i]]` to `varray[real_index_of.get(iarray[i])]`.

A running example could be:

```
int[] scores = new int[]{5, 7, 10, 3, 6};
int[] places = new int[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
quickSort(places, scores, 0, places.length - 1);
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(scores).mapToObj(Integer::toString).collect(joining(", ")));
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(places).mapToObj(Integer::toString).collect(joining(", ")));
```

With output:

```
5, 7, 10, 3, 6
3, 0, 4, 1, 2
```

(your output is wrong since `5` is the second lowest value)